# why map is looking stacked over another map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map apis for displaying map in my application. When i zoom out the map, it looks like a map is been stacked over another map. i.e seems like a layer of another map . How can avoid it and please why it is happening.
    enter code here

```
var map = angular.module('map', ['inventoryFilters', 'inventoryServices'])
.controller('mapCtrl', function ($scope, $filter, $http, JsonFileRepo) {
var filteritems = [];
filteredSites();
$scope.$on('filter-updated', function (event) {
    filteredSites();
 });

function filteredSites() {
    JsonFileRepo.getSites().
        then(function (sites) {
            filteritems = "";
            $scope.sitesInfo = sites;
            filteritems = $filter('applyRegionSelections')($scope.sitesInfo);
            filteritems = $filter('applySoftwareSelections')(filteritems);
            updateMap(filteritems);

        },
        function () {
            console.log('sites retrieval failed.');
        });
 };
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.0, -1.0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

$scope.markers = [];

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function createMarker (info) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.location.lat, info.location.lng),
        title: info.location.city,
       });
    marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.name + '</div>';
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
        (function (id) {
            return function(){
                infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
                infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                console.log("Floc id =" + id);
              };
        })( info.FLOCID)
    );

    $scope.markers.push(marker);

}

function updateMap(filteritems) {

    angular.forEach($scope.markers, function (marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    });

    $scope.markers.splice(0, $scope.markers.length);


    for (i = 0; i < filteritems.length; i++) {
        createMarker(filteritems[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what it looks like?  I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code; you don't have any event listeners for map zoom or bounds changed?

Comment: Sorry @duncan, I'm not able to provide a screenshot because i need ten reputation to add image.

Comment: @duncan, i'm providing a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1MZuLNeYtuhT2o2bVJwRDRBcHc/view?usp=sharing, you can now see what is happening?

Comment: Very strange.  Where do you call `updateMap` from?

Comment: @duncan, now i posting entire code of my controller.